# Function overwritting

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to overwrite a function or event handling in function?

Using addEventListener, we can have as many event handlers on element as much we want

```
var test=document.getElementById("div");
test.addEventListener("click",function(){alert("im first");},false);
test.addEventListener("click",function(){alert("im second");},false); // alerts "im first" and after that "im second"
```

but what if we want to overwrite function/event for example based on client width for example something like this

```
function one() {
    alert("first");
}

function two() {
    alert("second");
}

window.onresize = function() {
    var test = document.getElementById("div");
    if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
        test.onclick = one
    } else {
        test.onclick = two;
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would use very effective but very little known approach. [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) can accept an object with property `handleEvent` as event handler. In this case it's very easy to overwrite handler function, set it to `null` ot completely different function without messing with `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener` again and again.

In your case:

```
var test = document.getElementById("div");

var handlers = {
    handleEvent: function () {
        alert("im first");
    }
};

test.addEventListener("click", handlers, false);

function one() {
    alert("first");
}

function two() {
    alert("second");
}

window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
        handlers.handleEvent = one;
    } else {
        handlers.handleEvent = two;
    }
}
```

Check the demo below, resize the pane to see how it dynamically picks up different handlers based on viewport width.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/t4wrjkLa/

Comment: This is great! But how should i modife it when i want to pass an arguments into both functions?

Comment: For example like this `handlers.handleEvent = function(e) { one(arg1, arg2); };`

Comment: The problem is im using for loop to pass function with differents arguments to more elements.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have a reference to the original handler function, you can call [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) on it, and just add your own listener like normal.

```
function one()
{
    alert('first');
}
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.addEventListener('click', one);
// Later in your code
function two()
{
    alert('second');
}
test.removeEventListener('click', one);
test.addEventListener('click', two);
```

Demo:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event)
{
    test.removeEventListener('click', one);
    test.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        alert('second');
    });
    event.target.parentNode.removeChild(event.target);
});

function one()
{
    alert('first');
}
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.addEventListener('click', one);
```

```css
#test
{
    background: #CCC;
    border: solid 1px #666;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Click me</div> <button id="button">Exchange event listeners</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp).  You can remove the old event function then replace it with the new event function

```
function one() {
  alert("first");
}
function two() {
  alert("second");
}

window.onresize = function() {
  var test = document.getElementById("div");
  if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
    try{
    test.removeEventListener("click",two);
    } catch{}
    test.addEventListener("click",one,false);
  } 
  else {
    try{
    test.removeEventListener("click",one);
    } catch{}
    test.addEventListener("click",two,false);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not make links the primary part of your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Also, [don't use w3schools for reference](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a closure to reference the function currently set as the event handler:

```js
var onResize = function () {
    // references the current handler
    var curr;
    // removes/adds event handlers
    function swap (curr, repl) {
        var test = document.getElementById('div');
        test.removeEventListener('click', curr);
        test.addEventListener('click', repl);
    }
    // the "resize" event handler which will be
    // assigned to the "onResize" variable
    return function () {
        if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
            if (curr !== one) swap(curr, one);
            curr = one;
        } 
        else {
            if (curr !== two) swap(curr, two);
            curr = two;
        }
    };
}(); // IIFE

window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);

// run "onResize" at starting to
// set up one of the below handlers
onResize();
function one () { alert('first'); } 
function two () { alert('second'); }
```

```html
<div id="div">div</div>
```